# How to return an [out] variant with VT = VT_RECORD without creating memory leak in ole32.dll?

Tags: visual-c++, com, marshalling, atl, unmarshalling

Purify is pointing memory leak in ole32.dll while returning a **Variant** with VT set to **VT_RECORD** as **OUT parameter**. I am using **User Marshalling** by generating proxy/stub dll from IDL.
Can you suggest how to avoid this memory leak?

**Struct defined in IDL:**

```
{
BSTR m_sFirst;
BSTR m_sSecond;
VARIANT m_vChildStruct; //This member encapsulate a sub structure 
SAFEARRAY __RPC_FAR * m_saArray;
}CustomINFO;
```

**Encapsulation of struct in variant:**

I am allocating the memory for the structs using CoTaskMemAlloc and encapsulating it in Variant as follows:

```
vV->vt = VT_RECORD;
vV->pvRecord = pStruct; //Pointer of sturct
vV->pRecInfo = pRI; //RecordInfo Interface
```

Thanks

Picaro De Vosio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are limitations in support of VT_RECORD. 
Try checking with http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/4.htm, might help.

It might also be more helpful if you describe your case in more details (related IDL parts, commpiler version and code describing client/server communication which Purify suspects as leaking )